# Testsuite name property in instrumentation tests result xml

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing, android-instrumentation

I have a test suite in Android Studio that contains 3 test classes.

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({

        TestClass1.class,
        TestClass2.class,
        TestClass3.class
})

public class MyTestSuite {  }
```

When I run that test suite via gradle (`./gradlew connectedAndroidDevices`), I get a result.xml generated, which looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<testsuite name="com.example.TestClass1" tests="17" failures="1" errors="0" skipped="0" time="1.534" timestamp="2018-02-12T05:54:39" hostname="localhost">
  <properties>
    <property name="device" value="Nexus 5X - 8.0.0" />
    <property name="flavor" value="" />
    <property name="project" value="ExampleSdk" />
  </properties>
  <testcase name="getDefaultDescription" classname="com.example.TestClass1" time="0.029" />
  <testcase name="getCode" classname="com.example.TestClass1" time="0.0" />
  <testcase name="getDescription" classname="com.example.TestClass1" time="0.0" />
  <testcase name="testShouldRefresh" classname="com.example.TestClass2" time="0.03" />
  <testcase name="testCreateAuthorizationHeader" classname="com.example.TestClass2" time="0.0" />
  <testcase name="testHasExpired" classname="com.example.TestClass3" time="1.015" />
  ...
</testsuite>
```

Problem is, that the name property does not match the name of the test suite, but the name of the first class in that test suite:

`name="com.example.TestClass1` instead of `name="com.example.MyTestSuite`

Where is Gradle looking for that testsuite name?